# How to compare two ordered list in python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x

I have read some questions and answers about comparing two lists and returning matches in python3. They always apply set() to solve the problem. But my question should consider the order of elements and return unmatches of the second list. For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

b = [2,1,3,4,6]

Unmatch(a,b) = [2,1,6]
```

How to design the function Unmatch()? My basic idea is applying for loop to check each pair of items. Are there any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> l1= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                       
>>> l2 = [2, 1, 3, 4, 6]                       
>>> [l2_element for l1_element, l2_element in zip(l1, l2) if l1_element != l2_element]
[2, 1, 6]
```

If the 2 lists are not of the same length `zip` will stop when it reaches the end of the shorter list.

Comment: Fantastic! I love this method. Thank you! I am usually surprised by zip().